# month + date in Django queryset

Tags: python, django

In my Django app I am trying to export an excel reports by month created. The excel part works fine but I am unsure on how to filter by the month created.

model.py

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    ....
    creation = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^download/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/$', download_workbook),
```

views.py

```
def download_workbook(request, year, month):
    queryset = Claim.objects.filter(?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: (from [django documentation 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#month))

```python
data = Claim.objects.filter(
    creation__year=someyear,
    creation__month=somemonth,
)
```

p.s. use `Field Lookups` to filter data based on field type

Comment: :o that simple. Thanks